# How to override conversion operator in C++ template subclass?

Tags: c++, opencv, type-conversion, operator-overloading, operators

How to override conversion operator in C++ template subclass?
For example i try to implement subclass of Rect_ template class from openCv:

```
template<typename _Tp> class Rect_
{
public:
    typedef _Tp value_type;

    //! various constructors
    Rect_();
    Rect_(_Tp _x, _Tp _y, _Tp _width, _Tp _height);
    Rect_(const Rect_& r);
    Rect_(const Point_<_Tp>& org, const Size_<_Tp>& sz);
    Rect_(const Point_<_Tp>& pt1, const Point_<_Tp>& pt2);

    Rect_& operator = ( const Rect_& r );
    //! the top-left corner
    Point_<_Tp> tl() const;
    //! the bottom-right corner
    Point_<_Tp> br() const;

    //! size (width, height) of the rectangle
    Size_<_Tp> size() const;
    //! area (width*height) of the rectangle
    _Tp area() const;

    //! conversion to another data type
    template<typename _Tp2> operator Rect_<_Tp2>() const;

    //! checks whether the rectangle contains the point
    bool contains(const Point_<_Tp>& pt) const;

    _Tp x, y, width, height; //< the top-left corner, as well as width and height of the rectangle
};
```

My subclass ColorRect has additional field - color. How can i override conversion operator from parent class? If there is not possible, can i call conversion operator? How can i do it?

```
template<typename _Tp> class ColorRect_ : public cv::Rect_<_Tp>
{
    uchar color;

    ColorRect_(): cv::Rect_() { color = NONE; }
    ColorRect_(_Tp _x, _Tp _y, _Tp _width, _Tp _height, uchar color) : cv::Rect_(_x, _y, _width, _height), color(color)
    {

    }

    ColorRect_(const ColorRect_& r) : cv::Rect_(r), color(r.color) {}

    ColorRect_& operator = (const ColorRect_& r)
    {
        cv::Rect_<_Tp>::operator=(r);
        color = r.color;
        return this;
    }

    template<typename _Tp2> operator ColorRect_<_Tp2>() const
    {
        ... ?
    }
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unrelated but identifiers beginning with an underscore followed immediately by an uppercase letter are reserved in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can create non-explicit constructor to construct your class's instance from parent instance:

```
ColorRect_(const cv::Rect_<_Tp>& other) {...};
```

It will work the same way as conversion operator.